# Best way to copy global into shared memory

Tags: c++, cuda, gpu-shared-memory

Let's say I have a block of 32 threads that need to do random access a 1024 element array. I want to reduce the number of global memory calls by initially transferring the block from global to shared. I have two ideas to go about it:

A:

```
my_kernel()
{
    CopyFromGlobalToShared(1024 / 32 elements);
    UseSharedMemory();
}
```

or B:

```
my_kernel()
{
    if (first thread in block)
    {
        CopyFromGlobalToShared(all elements);
    }
    UseSharedMemory();
}
```

Which is better? Or is there another, better method?

Comment: I would say the first could be faster, if properly implemented, for the simple reason that all other threads will wait for the first thread to finish loading.

Answer (score 5):

A is better.

GPU has much higher mem bandwidth compared to CPU. However the peak bandwidth can only be achieved when threads running in the GPU follow a certain pattern.

This pattern requires the mem access to be coalesced. This means you need to use multiple threads to access sequential addresses in the global mem, and pay special attention on the alignment.

You could find more details about Coalesced Access to Global Memory in CUDA docs.

http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-best-practices-guide/index.html#coalesced-access-global-memory

Comment: So the method I indicated as `A` is better/more "standard"?

Comment: Yes, A is much better if `CopyFromGlobalToShared()` is well implemented.

Answer (score 1):

A is better, but depending on the size of the element - not necessairly the best!

What you want is every thread accessing a neighbouring word of the size 32-bit (64-bit might work on newer hardware as well). If the element size is bigger, you may prefer to be a bit more fancy:

```
//assumes sizeof(T) is multiple of sizeof(int)
//assumes single-dimention kernel
//assumes it is launched for all threads in block
template <typename T>
__device__ void memCopy(T* dest, T* src, size_t size) {
    int* iDest = (int*)dest;
    int* iSrc = (int*)src;
    for(size_t i = threadIdx.x; i<size*sizeof(T)/sizeof(int); i+=blockDim.x)
        iDest[i] = iSrc[i];
    __syncthreads();   
}
```

Note: this will work for all memory transfers (global->global, global->shared, shared->global). This is true even old devices without unified memory addressing, because the function will be inlined.

The problem won't be present if you use a structure-of-arrays approach for bigger elements.